# UINavigation/TabBar transition animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, navigation, transition

How can I use `UIViewAnimationTransition` type in one of `UINavigation`/`TabBar` transitions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only way I've found is to disable the built in transition animations, and use your own. I use something like the following for a UINavigationController:

```
UIViewAnimationTransition  trans = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp;
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: trans forView: [delegate window] cache: YES];
[navController pushViewController:detailController animated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.

(For UINavigationController [there's a **private** `-pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app/2216226#2216226).)