# I want a page curl effect for ModalViewController

Tags: objective-c

how can we give page curl effect for ModalViewController can we give custom animation
if i use this code

```
PageThreeViewController *pagethreecontroller = [[PageThreeViewController alloc] 
               initWithNibName:@"PageThreeViewController" bundle:nil];


   //UIViewAnimationTransition trans = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp;
   [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
   [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
   [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:[self view] cache:NO];
   // do your view swapping here

   //[UIView setAnimationTransition: trans forView: [self view] cache: YES];
   [self presentModalViewController: pagethreecontroller animated: NO];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
```

I doesnot seem to work please help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

On iPhone OS 3.2 and later (including 4.0) you could just use:

```
PageThreeViewController *pagethreecontroller = [[PageThreeViewController alloc] 
               initWithNibName:@"PageThreeViewController" bundle:nil];


pagethreecontroller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;


[self presentModalViewController: pagethreecontroller animated: YES];
```

Note that, the animation will stop before the curl is complete (hence "partial" curl). This may not be what you like.

Comment: i know this but i dont want this animation as some say it is undocumented and anyway i dont want partial curl :( thanks for help

Comment: @mad: [Who said it's undocumented?!](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the transition on the [delegate window] instead of [self view]. That's how I did it to replace the standard animations for a UINavigation controller. The whole snippet I used is in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401403/uinavigation-tabbar-transition-animation/2404748#2404748).

Comment: i dont have navigation in my app

Comment: yes, but I think if you just change this line:
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:[self view] cache:NO];

to this:
  [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:[AppDelegate window] cache:NO];

Then what you have may work.