# How to change pop view controller animation on back button?

Tags: iphone, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I am pushing my view controller with the following statement :

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.customViewController animatedWithTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft];
```

Now  when I am pressing the back button I want to animate it with the uiviewanimationtransitionflipfromright .

like

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimatedWithTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft];
```

How Can I do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This helps you to animating the view in back button.

```
[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.375];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2):

For Push:

```
MainView *nextView = [[MainView alloc] init];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:NO];
                         [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                     }];
```

For Pop:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                     }];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5889757/1915820

Answer (score 1):

See here for doing custom back anim:

[Prevent the animation when clicking "Back" button in a navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119528/prevent-the-animation-when-clicking-back-button-in-a-navigation-bar/3127914#3127914)