# Confirm back button on UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I am using the `storyboard` for my app which is using `UINavigationController`. I would like to add a confirmation dialog to the default back button so the user does not log out accidentally. Is there some way to do this? I have found that I cannot simply access the back button when it has be automatically created by the `UINavigationController`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the answer of Александр Кундрюков
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62183616/4995249
This looks like a nice way to solve the problem and still use the default back button

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't intercept the back button in this way. The closest facsimile is to use your own `UIBarButtonItem` set to the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` and set an action to display your alert etc. I had a graphic designer create button images that look like the standard back button.

As an aside, I needed to intercept the back button for a different reason. I urge you to reconsider this design choice. If you are presenting a view where users can make changes and you want them to have the choice to save or cancel IMHO it's better to use 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons vs a back button with an alert. Alerts are generally annoying. Alternatively, make it clear that the changes your users are making are committed at the time they make them. Then the issue is moot.

Comment: Well its not a form, its just that if they log out by accident they'll have to reenter their information (security thing). Here's the thing, I'm not adding the back button. Its there by default when using the Storyboard, UIViewController, and segues (which I am). Even if I were doing something like you're describing, that back button would still be there.

Comment: you can still add a `leftBarButtonItem` to your storyboard and configure it. It would replace the back button.

Comment: I hadn't realized that setting `leftBarButtonItem` replaced the auto button. I now feel silly. Thanks!

Comment: @XJones yours is the better answer. I replaced the back button with a UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel and I'm poping manually. Also I added a UIBarButtonSystemItemSave as rightBarButtonItem. This is the most clean solution to cancel / replace the back button.

Answer (score 10):

How I worked around this situation is by setting the `leftBarButtonItem` to the `UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash` style (making it instantly obvious that they'll delete the draft item) and adding an alert view confirming the deletion. Because you set a custom `leftBarButtonItem` it won't behave like a back button, so it won't automatically pop the view!

In code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // set the left bar button to a nice trash can
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash
                                                                                          target:self
                                                                                          action:@selector(confirmCancel)];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex)
    {
        // The didn't press "no", so pop that view!
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)confirmCancel
{
    // Do whatever confirmation logic you want here, the example is a simple alert view
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                    message:@"Are you sure you want to delete your draft? This operation cannot be undone."
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

It's really as simple as that! I don't see the big issue, tbh :p

I have to add a disclaimer, though; doing this breaks the default navigation behaviour and apple might not like developers doing this. I haven't submitted any apps (yet) with this feature, so I'm not sure if apple will allow your app in the store when doing this, but be warned ;)

***UPDATE:*** Good news, everybody! In the meanwhile I've released an app ([Appcident](https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/appcident/id572686621?mt=8)) to the App Store with this behavior in place and Apple doesn't seem to mind.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can find the Back button view and add UITapGestureRecognizer to it.

If you look at this image:
[image: Back button screen]
Using this code:

```
@interface UIView (debug)
- (NSString *)recursiveDescription;
@end

@implementation newViewController
... 
NSLog(@"%@", [self.navigationController.navigationBar recursiveDescription]);
```

You can realize how to find the View of the Back button. It is **always** the last one in subviews array of the navigationbar.

```
2012-05-11 14:56:32.572 backBtn[65281:f803] <UINavigationBar: 0x6a9e9c0; frame = (0 20; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a9ea30>>
   | <UINavigationBarBackground: 0x6aa1340; frame = (0 0; 320 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6aa13b0>>
   | <UINavigationButton: 0x6d6dde0; frame = (267 7; 48 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6d6d9f0>>
   |    | <UIImageView: 0x6d70400; frame = (0 0; 48 30); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6d6d7d0>>
   |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x6d70020; frame = (12 7; 23 15); text = 'Edit'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6d6dec0>>
   | <UINavigationItemView: 0x6d6d3a0; frame = (160 21; 0 0); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6d6d3f0>>
   | <UINavigationItemButtonView: 0x6d6d420; frame = (5 7; 139 30); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6d6d4e0>>
```

So I used:

```
UIView *backButton = [[navBar subviews] lastObject];
[backButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(alertMsg)];
[tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[backButton addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

Tapping on back button and voilà:
[image: Back button was tapped]

Comment: Interesting. I have a few questions though. What guarantee do I have that the back button will always be the last object? And does adding a gesture recognizer remove the default behavior, or does it simply add a second action?

Comment: 1. No guarantee :) 2. Adding gesture recognizer omits all other gestures.

Comment: Well if there is no guarantee then it isn't a good solution. If Apple changes something in their code to change the order of the buttons in the list then my app will break and I will have a difficult bug to track down.

Comment: I've found that `UITapGestureRecognizer` is pretty much worthless. It doesn't handle the case where a user might tap and hold on a view and then release. Instead, I typically just use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with the `minimumPressDuration` property set to `0.0`. This effectively handles both tapping and long-pressing a button.

Comment: Never do this kind of subview-array-hack! Your app could break with new iOS versions and it is not that easy to understand for other people reading your code. Maybe not a problem now, but later on.  Thomas Vervest and @XJones answer is the right way to go.

Comment: And what if the user uses slide-back gesture?

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
protocol CustomNavigationViewControllerDelegate {
    func shouldPop() -> Bool
}

class CustomNavigationViewController: UINavigationController, UINavigationBarDelegate {
    var backDelegate: CustomNavigationViewControllerDelegate?

    func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        return backDelegate?.shouldPop() ?? true
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, CustomNavigationViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        (self.navigationController as? CustomNavigationViewController)?.backDelegate = self
    }

    func shouldPop() -> Bool {
        if (needToShowAlert) {
            showExitAlert()
            return false

        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it on iOS 11 and iOS 13 and it works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

I figured out an easy solution which works out of the box:

1.) You need to create a custom navigation controller:

```
//
//  MyNavigationController.swift
//

import UIKit

// Marker protocol for all the VC that requires confirmation on Pop
protocol PopRequiresConfirmation {}

class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

// MARK: - UINavigationBarDelegate Conformance
extension MyNavigationController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
    func navigationBar(_ navigationBar: UINavigationBar, shouldPop item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        guard shouldAskConfirmation(for: item) else {
            return true
        }

        self.askUserForConfirmation()
        return false
    }
    
    private func shouldAskConfirmation(for item: UINavigationItem) -> Bool {
        guard
            let vc = self.viewControllers.last(where: { $0.navigationItem === item}),
            vc is PopRequiresConfirmation
        else {
            return false
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
    func askUserForConfirmation() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Cancel Insertion",
            message: "Do you really want to go back? If you proceed, all the inserted data will be lost.",
            preferredStyle: .alert
        )
        
        alertController.addAction(
            .init(
                title: "Yes, cancel",
                style: .destructive,
                handler: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
            )
        )
        
        alertController.addAction(
            .init(
                title: "No, continue",
                style: .cancel,
                handler: nil
            )
        )
        
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

2.) Add the following code to all ViewControllers where you need the confirmation "PopRequiresConfirmation":

```
//
//  ViewController2.swift
//

import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, PopRequiresConfirmation {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do to easily make a custom back button that replicates the look of the default back button on iPhone and iPad, with code written out explicitly because I imagine I'll come here looking for this again at some point.

Put the following functions somewhere in the implementation (.m) file of the relevant UIViewController with a UINavigationController, and then in viewDidLoad run `[self setupBackButton];`

Whatever you'd like to do with the back button, put in the `backButtonPressed` function.

```
- (void)setupBackButton {
    UIImage *leftArrowImage;
    UIImage *pressedLeftArrowImage;
    UIButton *customBackButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 48, 30)];
    [customBackButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
    customBackButton.titleLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    [customBackButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customBackButton setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [customBackButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        leftArrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBarSilverBack.png"];
        pressedLeftArrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBarSilverBackPressed.png"];
    }
    else {
        leftArrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBarDefaultBack.png"];
        pressedLeftArrowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBarDefaultBackPressed.png"];
    }
    UIImage *stretchableLeftArrowImage = [leftArrowImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15.0 topCapHeight:0];
    UIImage *stretchablePressedLeftArrowImage = [pressedLeftArrowImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15.0 topCapHeight:0];
    [customBackButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [customBackButton setBackgroundImage:stretchableLeftArrowImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customBackButton setBackgroundImage:stretchablePressedLeftArrowImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [customBackButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *aCustomBackButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customBackButton];
    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:aCustomBackButtonItem];
}

- (void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"back button pressed");
}
```

To get the exact button pngs from iOS, I recommend the [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor).  After running the project and saving the images on iPad Retina simulator followed by the iPad non-retina simulator, look for the titles in the 'Common' folder in the simulator folder that will appear on your desktop. File names "UINavigationBar...Back(@2x).png" and "UINavigationBar...BackPressed(@2x).png" are what you want.

I'm also attaching the [default iOS (iPhone and iPad) back bar button pngs](http://cl.ly/153z0u043x3g) used in the code above as a convenience. Note that with iOS updates, the look of the default back barbuttonitems may change...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround: (Tested on iOS10 and 11)

**Add tap gesture recognizer to navigation bar:**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onBackPressed(gestureRecognizer:)))
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

cancelsTouchesInView = true ensures that the back button does not get the touch event.

**Handle the gesture:**

```
@objc func onBackPressed(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view).x < 100 else {
        return
    }
    // ... back button is pressed do what you wanted to
```

Instead of using 100 as magic number you can find the view containing the back button and use it's frame do detect touches on it.

Answer (score -1):

Easy peasy.  Just cover the button with a transparent UIControl and capture the touches.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

#define COVER_HEIGHT    44
    //make this an iVar:  UIControl *backCover;
    if ( backCover == nil ) {
        CGRect cFrame = CGRectMake( 0, self.view.frame.origin.y-COVER_HEIGHT, 100, COVER_HEIGHT);
        backCover = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame:cFrame]; // cover the back button
        backCover.backgroundColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2]; // transparent
        // use clearColor later
        [backCover addTarget:self action:@selector(backCoverAction:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [self.view.window addSubview:backCover];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [backCover removeFromSuperview]; // prevent coverage on another view
    backCover = nil;
}

- (void)backCoverAction:(UIControl *)sender
{
    // decide what to do -- maybe show a dialog.
    // to actually go "Back" do this:
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // "Back"
}
```

This scheme also works for tabBar buttons, but it's more complex to determine the location.

Comment: There are other ways to navigate back besides the visible Back button. And covering a button with another breaks accessibility. Please don't do things this way.