# IOS navigation back event

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

There is a `willmoveToParentViewController` to catch back event between view controllers.

I have form . when user click `back` button I want to check if he made changes and give him warning about lost his data.

How can I stop back event ?

Comment: What do you mean by terminate ?

Comment: it means - wait until data saved or something then go back. Why not create you custom "back" button and in backPressed: selector handle logic you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564924/confirm-back-button-on-uinavigationcontroller check answer 2.

Comment: Can you post the code where you call willmoveToParentViewController?

Answer (score 0):

you can present an alert view controller that eseentially freezes any further action until the user deals with the alert view. Perhaps add an "OK" and "Cancel" button, OK goes back, cancel stays. Make the body say 'Warning, unsaved changes will be lost" or something.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/