# How to change the animation direction of ViewController on PopViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Is it possible to change the Direction of ViewContoller Pop animation.
Right now when we push VC at the time it shows animation Slide Left-to-Right and on Pop Right-to-Left.
But i want animation Slide Left-to-Right on Pop VC.

I have tried to use `UIViewAnimationTransition`.

```
[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.375];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But it doesn't have the animation i need which is Slide Left-to-Right. This is the animation i get

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
} UIViewAnimationTransition;
```

Comment: Try :- First show animation and on the completion of the animation pop the Viewcontroller.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Crashalot , I have added answer for the code i have used, please check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used following code..

Add this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //This line of code needed so you will not see the back window when its pop, match it with your app design.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return YES;
}
```

Where your **POP** code add this code,

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.4f;
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition
                                            forKey:kCATransition];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Check the result in this GIF,
http://www.giphy.com/gifs/l2YSeBELE1phMEd5S

Answer (score 9):

Cheers, here is the swift 3.0 ~ 4.0 version.

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.4
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[UIView beginAnimations:]` for your case. `setTransitionStyle` as you need. check avalable `UIViewAnimationTransitionStyle` in apple documentation refer this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Comment: Thanx for reply. Actually i have tried it but it doesnt have the animation i need which is Slide Left-to-Right.

Comment: I have used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942221/how-to-change-pop-view-controller-animation-on-back-button code which is nice but doent contain animation i need.

Answer (score 0):

```
let story = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")  as! SecondViewController

    UIView.beginAnimations("", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1.0)
    UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.easeInOut)
    UIView.setAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.flipFromRight, for: (self.navigationController?.view)!, cache: false)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(story, animated: true)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use completion block to do the job after animation:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75, animations: { () -> Void in

     UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.easeInOut)
     self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3, 3);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    // for zoom out
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

        self.myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
    //View ANimation
    [UIView transitionWithView: self.navigationController.view
                      duration: 0.5
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                    animations: ^{

                        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                    }
                    completion: nil ];
```