# Noobish Questions

Tags: inheritance, view, window, xamarin.ios, screens

I have two quick questions.

The first is, navigation from screen to screen (or maybe view to view). I know that there is navigation controller but it has a slide animation and im really looking for that flip animation that the iphone has.  Does anyone know what control to use or direct me to a good site about navigations.

The second question is about inheritance, I am current designing an app  that will have a base format of a title bar that will appear on all screens and a few other components.  So basically wondering how i should be going about this? example/website tips would be helpful basically not sure if its best to use windows or views.

I am currently new to monotouch normally develop using C# and Java.  Many thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UINavigationController and have it perform other animations to navigate among different controllers. Here is an example, but in Objctive-C:

[How to change the Push and Pop animations in a navigation based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app)

As far as your second question, you can create a base object that inherits from UIViewController and derive from it, but it is a little bit more complicated than inheriting simple objects. You have to learn some basics about how UIViewControllers and Interface Builder work.