# Page flipping efffect in ipad app

Tags: ios, ipad, page-curl, page-flipping

I have different xib files in which each has tableview.When an item in tableview is clicked,next xib file is to be shown.I used presentModalViewController and achieved the result.

My problem is that when the tableviewcell is selected,the next xib should be appeared with a Page flipping effect like that of a book.

I found some samples but that doesn't help.

Please reply,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i think this is your answer. you have to set curl effect in animatin [How to change the Push and Pop animations in a navigation based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app)