# Change duration of UINavigationController Push Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation

I like the default "push" animation that the UINavigationController uses, but I want to slow it down to about 1.0 seconds. Any advice?

PS- I tried using CATransition with kCATransitionPush and kCATransitionFromRight, but i got a weird fade-to-white effect that was undesirable.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app

Answer (score 0):

In my app (flashcard app) I use this code:

```
FlashCardFlipVC * flipvc = [[FlashCardFlipVC alloc] initWithFlashCardData:_card];
flipvc.navigationItem.title = self.navigationItem.title;

[UIView  beginAnimations:@"ShowAnswers" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: flipvc animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[flipvc release];
```

It sets different than normal animation pattern (curl up instead of slide) and different time setting. You can use your own of course.

Comment: This works for alternative animations, but I want to keep the push-from-the-right effect. As far as I know, this way does not allow that.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried setting setAnimationDuration:?

Comment: Before you "push" run that method (eg maybe when you instantiate it) from your navcontroller eg: [nav setAnimationDuration:0.5f];

Comment: nav? do you mean this? 'GameViewController *game = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:game animated:YES];  ' because this doesnt work

Comment: Well since you didn't show any source code, I had no idea what your navigation controller was called. What I mean is this (before pushing): [self.navigationController setAnimationDuration:0.5f];

Comment: UINavigationController doesn't have a setAnimationDuration method.

Comment: It inherits UIView that does however.