# Swiping left/right quickly, makes the UIImageView fly off the screen

Tags: ios, swipe-gesture

Following from @Rob's answer in the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407713/1692914

@Rob

Thanks for your example. I have a problem though, if I swipe the screen quickly what happens is the imageViews fly from left to right (or vice versa) depending on the animation and they disappear from the screen without appearing in the view as they should when I swipe the screen slowly.