# iOS: Change image position as it scrolls in/out of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I come from a web dev background and I'm trying to create something similar to [this technique](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/2138_SimpleParallax/Demo/index.html) for iOS (using Cocoa/Obj C). I'm having a lot of difficulty googling resources because "parallax" in iOS tends to refer to the floating content illusion introduced in iOS 7.

To clarify, I have an image at the top and content below. As the user scrolls down, I would like the image to appear as though it's scrolling up at a slower rate and is being covered by the content, rather than simply pushed up.

Does anyone know of any existing libraries, tutorials, or anything that can help me accomplish this? I'm a bit stuck at the moment, and my lack of experiencing in Obj C is making it difficult to try to implement this on my own. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979549/parallax-view-scrolling-yahoo-weather-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are open source projects you can use as a reference to add Parallax scrolling using `UIScrollView`:

- QMBParallaxScrollViewController: https://github.com/quemb/QMBParallaxScrollViewController
- A3ParallaxScrollView: https://github.com/allaboutapps/A3ParallaxScrollView
- RBParallaxScrolling: https://github.com/ralfbernert/RBParallaxScrolling

Searching for `Parallax UIScrollView` will bring your more relevant examples that are not related to the parallax effect of iOS 7. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.