# How to make iOS App background change with scrolling up/down

Tags: ios, scroll, background

I'm trying to make the background and text change as the user scrolls up or down. Similar to what Apple uses on their website pages like this http://www.apple.com/iphone/why-theres-iphone/

How can I do this effect?

Comment: Can you post an example of your code that isn't working?

Comment: hey @rickywooz - you there bud?!

Answer (score 1):

It's not THAT easy to do this, unfortunately.

in the first instance, you must **learn about gestures** in iOS.

`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`

Your question is of an extremely general nature, and there are 1000s of immediately accessible easy tutorials on using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` so you should work through those.

Secondly you have the general concept of "sliding pages around" in iOS.

[image: sliders]

It rather depends on precisely what you are trying to achieve, but this for example would be a good first step for you to implement while you are learning about these basic concepts:

[sliding screens tutorial on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26024779/294884)

Answer (score 0):

If you are to change UIView background in scroll up/down, you first need "UIScrollView" to be added in the main UIView of the ViewController. Then you should use the UIScrollView delegate method:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView == yourScrollView) {
       //change background according to the scrollview content offset.
       if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > some_value && scrollView.contentOffset.y < some value) {
        scrollView.backgroundImage = your_image
        }
    }
}
```

Before using you should conform the delegate "UIScrollViewDelegate".