# How to create UIPageViewcontroller within container using iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

I am trying to create `"UIPageView as a portion of a screen"` within `mainviewcontroller`. Below `storyboard` connection I am trying for that. Now the problem is I can connect `container to UIPageViewcontroller` but `Pageviewcontroller` of multiple view controller size not changing. 
Please find below Images and give me any solution and examples.

**Actual**
[image: Actual]

**Expectation**

[image: Expectation]

Comment: please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398796/uipageviewcontroller-and-storyboard

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please provide any basic samples, Because I am new for iOS and moreover I am trying by Objective C.@Ansha

Comment: check this http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: I know very well about UIPageviewcontroller like above reffernce URL. Now my problem is I can't show the Pageviewcontroller small rectangle size.@AnshaD

Comment: you should use a small container view which you need to show the pages

Comment: See I have posted above storyboard image. I did that but its not showing small size. thats my exact question. @AnshaD

Comment: self.pageViewController.view.frame = self.containerView.frame;
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

Comment: Cool!...I did by some scrollview method buddy.Thank you!