# How to create a slide navigation menu(off-canvas-menu) in swift without storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, off-canvas-menu

I want to create an off-canvas-menu in swift without using a storyboard. There are lots of examples out there for creating that menu but all use storyboard. Even creating it programmatically  is fine for me.
I want to create the slide nav using xib files not storyboard.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIPageViewController and storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398796/uipageviewcontroller-and-storyboard)

Comment: @JoeBlow I am using xib files not storyboard.

Comment: ok, but *"Our app has lots of screens and it gets difficult to maintain with a single storyboard"* ... just use lots of storyboards??  generalize to a container view.  Anyway sorry I don't have answer to your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure out the solution. I used the following library which can be used for both storyboards and xib files. The good thing about it is it's mostly done programmatically.
https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController