# UIPageViewContoller in container view with page control icon

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol, uicontainerview

I am writing a Swift app with three views. I have achieved this by putting a UIPageViewController inside a container and having that switch when you swipe, from another Stack Overflow article: [UIPageViewController and storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398796/uipageviewcontroller-and-storyboard/26024779#26024779). I would also like to have dots on the bottom indicating the page you are on. But, the UIPageControl I am using can only be placed on the view controller with the container, and the code with the current page is in the page controller's code. Here is my code:

```
class ContainerView : UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myPageController: UIPageControl!
}

class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var pages = [UIViewController]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page1ID")
        let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page2ID")
        let page3: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Page3ID")
        pages.append(page1)
        pages.append(page2)
        pages.append(page3)
        setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!
        if (currentIndex == 0) {
            return pages[currentIndex]
        }
        let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)
        //myPageControl.currentPage = previousIndex
        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex = pages.index(of: viewController)!
        if (currentIndex == 2) {
            return pages[currentIndex]
        }
        let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
        //myPageControl.currentPage = nextIndex
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

}
```

How could I access the parent view controller (ContainerView) from the child in the container (MyPageViewController)? I'm new to Swift/Objective-C but have programmed in other languages (C++, Python). If you need the storyboard, please ask.