# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for sub view controllers of UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am using [@Fattie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26024779/1157173) and it works great.
However, while paging too fast i am getting the following error:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   UIViewController

There is a single message for each sub view controller.

I haven't found an answer for that specific case here in SO.

Comment: are you segueing or instantiating the viewcontrollers? Perhaps you post some code regarding this