# How to create guided tour tutorial for iOS app?

Tags: ios

I am looking at options for add tutorial/help information to my iOS application.  Many apps, primarily games will have guided tutorials.  My app is for business owners, and primarily uses TableView Controllers.

Are there frameworks, or built-in support for creating a guided tours of an iOS app that uses TableView Controllers?

Wondering if there are options that would guide the user through making the actual actions, as opposed to having them read through pages in a PageViewController.

Comment: Your app is custom.. thus your tour should be custom. Many games make their own guided tour primarily because the game itself has a unique idea or implementation.. or it's very specific.

Comment: @Brandon - I understand that what I need is custom.  What I am wondering about, is since I am using standard widgets, like TableViews and TableViewCells, if there was someway of visually highlighting the subviews in a view, like a mask with annotations over the actual view.  Seems like there should be tools to help facilitate this, reducing the amount of custom code I need.

Comment: hi @Brandon, that's totally wrong dude.  huge numbers of apps use almost exactly the same help systems - whether the popular "scrolling intro pages" or "coaching points"

Comment: @DaveDude - here's exactly how to do "scrolling intro pages" as on most social media, etc.  fortunately it's very easy these days.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26024779/294884

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following link has what I think you are looking for. It allows you to create walkthroughs and guided tours (coach marks) in a simple way, with Swift.

https://github.com/ephread/Instructions

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thx for sharing.