# How can I create a scrollable view in Swift?

Tags: iphone, swift

I want to create a simple app to show three different views in which I can put some informations and buttons.

I would like to know how can I implement it.

Is it possible to do it in a single view?

Is it raccomandabile using the ScrollView?

I would like to start my application from the center view, allowing my users to swipe left or right to navigate in the pages.

Comment: Yes, I know what Swift is. I mean in Xcode, how can I create an app like I described before?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `PageViewController`. Search this term in Google or YouTube and you will highly likely find tons of good tutorials. Also, check the following links:

- **Another post in StackOverflow:** [UIPageViewController and storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398796/uipageviewcontroller-and-storyboard/26024779#26024779)
- **Apple's Documentation on Page View Controllers:** https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html
- **A video tutorial in Youtube:** [Snapchat-like menu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_daE3IL_1s)