# iOS tableview inside pageviewcontroller inside scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview

I want to put a tableView inside a pageviewcontroller which is inside a scrollview.

So I have in my storyboard :

[image: soryboard]

All constraints are respected like this

[image]

I disabled the tableview scroll but my scroll doesn't scroll, my tableView in **TestVC1** not expand the *PagerPlace* in **TestVC**

How can I make my scrollview scroll and its content size depends on the tableview height + my red view?

**EDIT**

I tried your solution, then I got a storyboard like this : 
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8x17.png)

Then my scrollview doesn't scroll, I don't know why,

Comment: No, I want a scrollView in TestVC, which is contains : a header (red box), something like a pageviewcontroller (with tabs (white box)) and in a children of the uipageviewcontroller, I have a tableview with custom size, So I want to scroll ALL the page and not only my tableview

Comment: Here's my classic answer on UIPageViewController - maybe it will help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398796/uipageviewcontroller-and-storyboard/26024779#26024779

Comment: No it doesn't page left and right

Comment: Are you just saying there is ONE table view, which sits under the red area?  is that right?

Comment: In my case I got 2 childrens of uipageviewcontroller which each one got 1 tableview, but imagine if only 1 tab has a tableview and the other not, How can I implement it ?

Comment: the answer is with container views - see answer!

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your effect perfect.

`Scroll View -> UIPageViewController's view -> UITableView`

> Scroll View has a subview of UIPageViewController's view,

> UIPageViewController has many page, one page ( a controller's view ) has a subview of UITableView

---

Yeah. You can change the solution.

`mainScrollView ( vertical slide ) -> contentScrollView ( horizontal slide  ) -> contentStackView ( has many pages) -> UITableView ( one page )`

mainScrollView is UIScrollView, slides in vertical,

contentScrollView is UIScrollView, slides in horizontal

`contentScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true`

that simulates `UIPageViewController`

contentStackView has many pages, one page is your UITableView

---

To make it work like this:

> How can I make my scrollview scroll and its content size depends on the tableview height + my red view?

for the part above the UITableView

```
   public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        if scrollView == mainScrollView {
            // vertical
            let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            if offsetY >= sillValue {
                scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: sillValue)
                currentChildScrollView?.am_isCanScroll = true
                scrollView.am_isCanScroll = false
            } else {
                let negScroll = (scrollView.am_isCanScroll == false)
                if negScroll{
                    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: sillValue)
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

for the UITableView part

use KVO to controller the base scroll view's offset Y ,

and UITableView's offset Y is by default.

```
let keyValueObservation = currentChildScrollView?.observe(\.contentOffset, options: [.new, .old], changeHandler: { [weak self] (scrollView, change) in
            guard let self = self, change.newValue != change.oldValue else {
                return
            }
            self.childScrollView(didScroll: scrollView)
        })



internal func childScrollView(didScroll scrollView: UIScrollView){
        let scrollOffset = scrollView.am_originOffset.val
        
        let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        
        if scrollView.am_isCanScroll == false {
            scrollView.contentOffset = scrollOffset
        }
        else if offsetY <= scrollOffset.y {
            scrollView.contentOffset = scrollOffset
            scrollView.am_isCanScroll = false
            mainScrollView.am_isCanScroll = true
        }
    }
```

#### [the full code in github](https://github.com/coyingcat/PagedControllerOnScrollView/tree/main/Aquaman)