# Setting UIScrollView frame to view size in IB

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, childviewcontroller

I'm trying to duplicate the functionality from [this](https://github.com/lbrendanl/SwiftSwipeView) gitHub repo. It is the solution to a question somebody else asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687140/snapchat-like-swipe-navigation-between-views-in-xcode-6-and-swift).

When I download the project from gitHub, I can run it without problems on any size iPhone in the simulator, even though in the storyboard the ViewController and ScrollViews' sizes are set to 4-inch iPhone. I'm not sure how that can be because there are no constraints. I put in a print statement that returns the width of the ScrollView, and it returns 320px no matter what device I'm running it on.

Now if I start a new project and copy all the files into the new project and try running it again, it works fine on a 4-inch iPhone, but no longer fills the screen on larger devices, as I would expect.

What in the world is going on here, and is it good practice?

Comment: Obviously, you have to make sure that the constraints for ScrollView are set well either by 'AutoLayout' or 'Springs & Structs'.

Comment: perhaps a missing default launch image issue? i recall some time agao i was missing Default-568h@2x.png so stuff i ran on an iphone 5 showed up at iphone 4 sizes.  not sure if the same will hold true here but worth a look.