# Changing a ViewController's transition direction?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, monotouch.dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the Push and Pop animations in a navigation based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app)

Using MonoTouch and MonoTouch.Dialog, I have a `DialogViewController` that I'm pushing onto a  `UINavigationController` and when I do so it makes the current screen being displayed move off from right to left.  I was wondering how I would go about reversing that, making the current screen be "pushed off" left to right, like when you press a back button.
My code is below, where _root is a RootElement.

```
_viewController = new DialogViewController(_root, false);
_navController.PushViewController(_viewController, true);
```

EDIT: I've tried using _viewController.ModalTransitionStyle and such to no avail if this information helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer by searching Stack Overflow. For instance here:
[How to change the Push and Pop animations in a navigation based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app)

```
MainView *nextView = [[MainView alloc] init];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                             [super pushViewController:nextView animated:NO];
                             [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                         }];
```

This easily translates in MonoTouch and will become something like (untested):

```
UIView.Animate(0.75f, 0f, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, delegate {
                navController.PushViewController(...);
                UIView.SetAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.FlipFromRight, navController.View, false);
            }, null);
```