# uipageviewcontroller driven by a uitableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a uitablewview based app where clicking on a cell will push a new view. What I would like to do it is rather than do a push animation to the new view, I would like to perform a page flip animation like that found in iBooks.

I presume I would have to create a uipageviewcontroller and use uitableview to turn the pages.

I'm not really sure how to code this though. Can anyone show me some code to get started with please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UINavigationController and do the push/pop with animated == NO and instead use a custom animation. See this excellent post on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5889757/289843

The animations for the page flip effect are UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp and UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown.

Comment: Brilliant! My only issue is that i'm using segues, so while I can animate the 'push' i'm not sure how to animate the 'pop' when the user clicks the back button that appears after the 'push'....

Comment: The only way I can think of is to replace the backbutton on your view controller with a custom button. You can do this by assigning your custom button to <viewController>.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem. However this won't have the arrow shape of normal back buttons.