# how to have animation like pop instead of push in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using following code:

```
FirstView * fir=[[FirstView alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:fir animated:NO];
```

I want to be an animation like popview controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are pushing the viewcontroller, But you want the animation of popping? Strange!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(void)ButtonAction:(id)sender{
  [self SwipeRight:self.navigationController.view];  // <--calling method
  //[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontrollerobject animated:NO];
  // or pop // 
}

    -(void)SwipeRight:(UIView *)view{

        CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        [transition setDuration:0.3];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
        [transition setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
        [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition]; 
    }

    -(void)SwipeLeft:(UIView *)view{
        CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        [transition setDuration:0.3];
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
        [transition setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];
        [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition]; 
    }
```