# navigationcontroller having same animation as [self presentViewController: ...]

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Is there anyway to have the navigation controller present the view animation as how presentViewController does it, where the view appears from the bottom and comes up?

Answer (score 0):

See this post on how to do custom animations for push segues:

[How to change the Push and Pop animations in a navigation based app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app)

You can find all the UIViewAnimationOptions here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptions