# Working implementation of slide up/down transition using UINavigationControllerDelegate on iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, transition

I've been spending some time trying to sort out custom transition animations available in iOS 7. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app), `UINavigationControllerDelegate` is the way to go.

There are, however, no examples or documentation describing how best to approach a simple vertical transition in iOS7. (There are a [plethora of other transition styles using `UINavigationControllerDelegate`](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-7-tutorial-series-custom-navigation-transitions-more), but none as simple as sliding the view up and down -- there are others that suggest just modifying the view position, but that seems like a tacky hack?). There are yet [others too that go as far back to 2011](http://blog.yetanotherjosh.com/post/33685102199/3-ways-to-do-a-vertical-transition-with), but they're obviously not using `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

> **Can anyone provide a basic working implementation of a simple slide up/down transition using `UINavigationControllerDelegate`?**

Disclaimer: I would love to provide code, but since there isn't any code yet to post... I did however create a simple example using jQuery that shows what I'm trying to achieve.

Check out that fiddle <kbd>[`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/remus/8L4bM/)</kbd>

Comment: The section in my book on custom transition animations is really very good (even if I do say so myself). And there are half a dozen examples at my [github site](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples) to get you started. It isn't at all difficult (though my book does explain some things that might not be immediately obvious).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> there are others that suggest just modifying the view position, but that seems like a tacky hack

No, it's not a tacky hack. That's what you do. A custom transition animation simply means that you are in charge of bringing the new view into the scene - provided it ends up in the right place. So the way to animate it in from the bottom is simply to position it at the bottom and animate it up into place.

So for example (taken almost directly from the example code in my book):

```
-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    // boilerplate
    UIViewController* vc1 = 
        [transitionContext 
            viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController* vc2 = 
        [transitionContext  
            viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView* con = [transitionContext containerView];
    CGRect r1start = [transitionContext initialFrameForViewController:vc1];
    CGRect r2end = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:vc2];
    UIView* v1 = vc1.view;
    UIView* v2 = vc2.view;
    // end boilerplate

    CGRect r = r2end;
    r.origin.y += r.size.height; // start at the bottom...
    v2.frame = r;
    [con addSubview:v2];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        v2.frame = r2end; // ... and move up into place
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    }];
}
```

That code is adapted from my example at https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p292customAnimation1/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.m The example is almost exactly what you are describing except it's for a tab controller instead of a navigation controller and it comes in from the side instead of the bottom. But the principle is exactly the same.

Comment: Yeah, that example is great. Thanks again -- and I'm sure the next bloke to come along searching for an up/down implementation will appreciate it too!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the flow. I tried to simplify as much as I can.

[image][image][image][image]