# Animating elements of views that are being transitioned to

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a question regarding the transition in this gif:

[image]

It's a beautiful app called Dark Sky.

How does one start animating things in the *upcoming* view on the transition?

Is this multiple views animating in one view controller, or multiple view controllers animating in and out?

Here as we scroll to the next view, we see the elements are appearing independent from each other and moving independently from each other as well.

Comment: I wonder if this is UIKit Dynamics at work? There's a WWDC 2013 video on UIKit Dynamics and scroll views that might be useful. But I really don't know for sure.

Comment: I think it is one large view (three pages wide) inside of a UIScrollView, with a page control at the bottom.

Comment: This is something that [UIScrollViewDelegate scrollViewDidScroll:] would let you do. But then there are many ways to perform this "transition."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking a look at [Apple's WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#217) video for session 217. They do something similar with the lock screen on an iPhone.

Specifically, it appears that the Dark Sky app uses nested `UIScrollViews`. Each of those "rows" is itself a `ScrollView` inside a paging `ScrollView`. When the overall "page" of the outer `ScrollView` is dragged, they will programmatically wait for a certain point in the scroll for each of those rows to "catch" and then follow along with the outer scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

I too am a fan of this transition so I took a shot at it:

[image]

The source code is on [Github](https://github.com/benpackard/DarkSkyDemo) and I wrote up my implementation in a [blog post](http://www.benpackard.org/blog/?p=36).

> As the user navigates, I capture the scroll position. I then convert
>   this into a ‘scroll factor’ for each of the pages. Each page’s scroll
>   factor is a number between -1 and 1, representing its distance from
>   view. When a page’s scroll factor is 0, that page is front and center
>   in the app. A scroll factor of -1 means that the page is at least one
>   screen-width off to the left, and +1 means the same in the opposite
>   direction.
>
> Each page is constantly told its new scroll factor as the user moves
>   through the app. In response, the page tweaks each of its labels.
>   There is an autolayout constraint pinning each label to the left edge.
>   This constraint’s constant is adjusted in proportion to its vertical
>   position on the page – in other words, the top labels move around less
>   that the bottom labels.
>
> To round off the effect, the same scale factor can be used to adjust
>   the transparency of each label as the page slides in and out of view.

Answer (score -1):

If your deploy target is above 7, you can use UINavigationControllerDelegate.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21796231/1215715

If not, there's a good opensource library ADTransitionController

https://github.com/applidium/ADTransitionController/blob/master/ADTransitionController/ADTransition.h

Comment: I am aware of the ios7 transition methods. As you can see in the animation, view elements have different animation speeds which has nothing to do with transition controllers... Thanks though.

Comment: I don't see this as a navigational stack of view controllers (but I guess it's possible). It looks like a plain vanilla scroll view or a UIPageViewController.