# How to make UINavigationController push from left?

Tags: ios

By default the UINavigationController is pushing a new view controller from right to left. However, I need it to push from left to right to be accordance with my swipe gesture. Is there a way to do so? I am focusing on iOS 7.

Comment: Take a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app

Comment: @Paulo, but I don't want flip animation, just ordinary move is OK...This post seems not helpful on this.

Comment: HanXu, I am probably just going to state something you probably already know - there are very limited transition options from view to view and the list is the folioing: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions    - I see what you mean - the simple right to left is not available -  you probably want something right to left and back like a UIScrollview

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7 (only), you can easily do this with a *custom transition animation*. The animation can be automatic (the user taps a button and the animation just happens) or interactive (the user pans and the movement of the animation accompanies the gesture).

Comment: This downloadable example project happens to be for a tab bar controller, not a navigation controller, but it does show how to bring in a view from either side (left gesture or right gesture), and the basic principles are _exactly_ the same as for a navigation controller: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p296customAnimation2/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.m