# How can I use custom UIViewController transitions to achieve this?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I have a flow in my app where all the view controllers have the same gradient background (using a UIImageView).

I’m presenting each of them modally with a cross-dissolve transition as opposed to using a navigation controller because I don’t want the horizontal push/pop transition. Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps using a navigation controller and disabling the push/pop animation and just fading/pushing the UI elements into the view?

I want it to look like the background never changes through the workflow, but the ui elements/contents for each view controller do change.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a custom push / pop animation, if the animation is fairly easy to do.:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                             [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:NO];
                             [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                         }];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                             [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                         }];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app).

---

If the animation isn't so easy, it's perfectly fine to present your view controllers modally if you don't need the navigation bar, but you'll have to provide your own `popToViewController:animated:` equivalent (since I don't know any way to dismiss more than one view controller).