# How do I change the UINavigationController push transition style?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am using a navigation controller and push segues to control the flow of my app. Is there anyway to change the default animation of right-to-left for the push segues? Is there something I can overwrite somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: you can use this tutorial, http://www.objc.io/issue-12/custom-container-view-controller-transitions.html

I am used this to my app: http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-transition-ios-7/

Comment: is it not possible to do a transition such as flip horizontal that can be selected in the interface builder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did the following and it works fine.. and is simple and easy to understand..

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
//transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

And the same thing for push..

don't forget to include QuartCore (#import )

Comment: where do I put this code? does it work with the interface builder i.e. performSegue ?

Comment: I used this, it works nicely. Is there anyway to change the background color from black? It kind of flashes black when it transitions.

Comment: this works, only one draw back is that status/nav bar flickers.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app

Answer (score 1):

Yes , you can changes transition style of ViewController with different animation. see below link.

1. [transition style animation](http://www.objc.io/issue-12/custom-container-view-controller-transitions.html)
2. [ViewController transition](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html)
3. [Custom ViewController transition](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/)
4. [ADTransitionController](http://applidium.github.io/ADTransitionController/)
5. [transition](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-create-custom-viewcontroller-transitions/)
6. [ViewController T](http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-transition-ios-7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `NSObject` class and subclass it from `UIStoryboardSegue` and then override the `-(void)perform` function to give it your own custom animations.
There you can use any animations either pre-defined or your own.
For details, checkout [this link](http://blog.jambura.com/2012/07/05/custom-segue-animation-left-to-right-using-catransition/).