# How to change pushViewController animation duration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I simply push detail view controller in my app, but what I want is to speed up a little bit animation. I know that default time is 0.35, but can I somehow change that value for pushing another view controller? Code in Swift or Objective-C will be appreciated

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023528/how-do-i-change-the-uinavigationcontroller-push-transition-style) might be useful to you...

Comment: @AhmadF what is that ? may be you forgot to add link

Comment: I edited it. Also, you might want to check [Customizing the Transition Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html)

Answer (score 0):

try like :

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.70, animations: { () -> Void in
    UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut)
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(nextView, animated: false)
    UIView.setAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.FlipFromRight, forView: self.navigationController!.view!, cache: false)
})
```

Comment: FlipFromRight is not proper animation.

Comment: Probably should be `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight`.