# How to Push one UIview to another UIview in ios using Animation concept?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Hi I am very new in iOS and in my project I have added two `UIViews` programmatically on my main `UIViewController`.

Here my main requirement is when I click "Next" button which is in my `firstView`, I want to push the `FirstView` to `SecondView` and 
when I click "Back" button which is in the `SecondView`, I want to pushBack `secondView` to `firstView`.

As in how to push one `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController`?

But same requirement I want to do Using `UIView` programmatically.

Please help me.

How can we do this?

### my code:-

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    UIView * FisrtView;
    UIView * SecondView;

    UIButton * Next;
    UIButton * Back;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    FisrtView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    FisrtView.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    FisrtView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:FisrtView];

    SecondView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    SecondView.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    SecondView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:SecondView];

    Next = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    Next.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    Next.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [Next setTitle:@"Go Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Next addTarget:self action:@selector(Next:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [FisrtView addSubview:Next];

    Back = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    Back.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    Back.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [Back setTitle:@"Go Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Back addTarget:self action:@selector(Back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [SecondView addSubview:Back];


    //Applting Autolayouts for All Fields

    NSDictionary * HeaderDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(FisrtView,SecondView,Next,Back);

    //Appliying Autolayouts for FirstView

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[FisrtView]-0-|"]
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:HeaderDictionary]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[FisrtView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    //Appying Autolayoust for NextButton

    [FisrtView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[Next]-10-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    [FisrtView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-100-[Next(30)]"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

     //Appliying Autolayouts for secondView

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-0-[SecondView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-0-[SecondView]-0-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    //Appying Autolayoust for BackButton

    [SecondView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-10-[Back]-10-|"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];

    [SecondView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-100-[Back(30)]"]
                                                                      options:0
                                                                      metrics:nil
                                                                        views:HeaderDictionary]];


    SecondView.hidden = YES;
    FisrtView.hidden = NO;

}

-(void)Next:(id)sender{

    SecondView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);  //your view start position

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.15f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     [SecondView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];   // final visible position
                 }
                 completion:nil];
SecondView.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)Back:(id)sender{

    SecondView.hidden = YES;
    FisrtView.hidden = NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: what the error u faced

Comment: hi kartik there is no error i am facing i want to push one UIview to another UIview as like how we push one UIviewcontroller to another UIviewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initial mistake, you were create the button is wrong and does not set the frame to visible area

not like

```
Next = [[UIButton alloc] init];
```

do like

```
Next = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
Next.frame = CGRectMake(210, 285, 100, 18)];
Next.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[Next setTitle:@"Go Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[Next addTarget:self action:@selector(Next:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[FisrtView addSubview:Next];
```

and forget to add frame for visible area in view

```
FisrtView = [[UIView alloc] init];
FisrtView.frame = CGRectMake(210, 285, 100, 18)];

SecondView = [[UIView alloc] init];
SecondView.frame = CGRectMake(210, 285, 100, 18)];
```

for sample animation

```
-(void)Next:(id)sender{

SecondView.frame=CGRectMake(248, -420, 500, 414);  //your view start position

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     [SecondView setFrame:CGRectMake(248, 30, 500, 414)];   // final visible position
                 }
                 completion:nil]; 
}
```

for sample animation see this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk_uiview-animations--mobile-10706)

Comment: but your coding is correct, view we wont push in your concept hide and show only

Comment: hi kartik i think you can't understand my requirement is i want to push one UIview to another UIview as like how we push one UIviewcontroller to another UIviewcontroller

Comment: see in our ipad there you click settings button then you tap notification button threre is clearly push on UIview to another UIview then how is it's not possible here?

Comment: @Krish -- bro in UIView in singe viewcontroller , we cant use push one UIviewcontroller to another UIviewcontroller  conept , in this place we can show and hide use some animation with delay

Comment: that's what i am expecting how to use animations with delay please help me brother

Comment: @Krish -- sorry for delay my mac was hanged, check the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95117/discussion-between-krish-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link. 
hope this will help you.

http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app&ei=Qc-ODruI&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=775&ts=1447514312&sig=APONPFlwklDRNHSybRHp3xVcrDKmQUeRjg