# How to open new view controller on uitabbaritem on button click

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on uitabbarcontroller. When i click on one tabbaritem at that time i am place two button at the top of view and want to open different view on button click, i don't want to move to another view, the uitabbaritem at the bottom should be remaining the same.

[image: Please look at this picture]

here i want to open different view on *Company profile* and *My profile*.

[image: Please check my structure of storyboard]

> how can i add scrollview with containor view. i am using this structure in below image

[image: This is the structure i used, more contents i need to add in the embedded view on container view]

Comment: hello sir, i think this tutorial will not help me, i don't want any back button, i just want to open a view when click on (company profile)  and again change view when click on (My profile). The buttons at the top will be visible when open any view.

Comment: hello sir Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: sure my bro which type output u need, once see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706790/how-to-push-one-uiview-to-another-uiview-in-ios-using-animation-concept/33706905#33706905

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, i just want that when i click on profile item(see my attached image) on uitabbaritem a default view will open for company profile and then if i click on MY profile a view will open with the same size.

Comment: ok fine now what the issue u faced... and where you struck

Comment: This is the structure i am using in Storyboard, My problem is i am unable to present a view on click of (My profile ) button. i want to override these views on the click of company profile and my profile.

Comment: no bro , is not comes inside else if you need this use "Containerviewcontroller", or else push viewcontroller, in this scenario above answer does not work.

Comment: Thanks sir i think it will work for me, but there is one query from my side, i have to add lots of textfield button and label on view so can i use it scrollview in it easily???

Comment: ya but you need to retrive the value from that view controller then you go for delegate /protocol

Comment: hello sir, how can i add uiscrollview inside the child view of uicontainor. Please help me in this scenario.

Comment: hello sir please help me, i added a new screenshot of my problem

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating the two buttons programatically, you can also create the view programatically when the button is clicked.

Use the button's addTarget Method to create the views and add them to the viewcontroller.

I think in your case, it would be better to create a new viewcontroller and present it modally, instead of creating a view and adding it.