# Swift: Current View Controller is re-displayed during transition to the next View Controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, transition, presentviewcontroller

When I call View Controller B (`ProfileController`) from View Controller A, using `self.present(navControllerProfile, animated: false, completion: nil)`, View Controller A is displayed again quickly before switching to B. I use the same code to call other View Controllers from View Controller A and the transition works perfectly, only the transition to B presents this "bug". Has anyone ever come up with a similar problem and managed to solve it? Thank you.

```
if self.view?.window == nil {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
}
self.view.window?.layer.add(self.transition, forKey: kCATransition)
if let profileInstantiated = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileController") as? ProfileController{
    let navControllerProfile = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profileInstantiated)
    //Transition with "bug" bellow
    self.present(navControllerProfile, animated:false, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests and unable to detect the cause of the problem, I finally solved the bug by applying the solution proposed by **HotJard** in this link: [How to present view controller from right to left in iOS using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722323/how-to-present-view-controller-from-right-to-left-in-ios-using-swift)