# How do I present ViewController programatically?

Tags: swift, storyboard, presentviewcontroller

```
import UIKit

//EventList ViewController
class EventPage: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
    }
    
}

class EventForm: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        }
    
    //IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var eventNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fromTimePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var toTimePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var colorPreview: UIView!

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        
        //empty text field
        eventNameField.text = ""
    }
    
    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
        if (eventNameField.hasText) {
            
            //fix error handling
            eventNameField.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray2
            
            //pull data from fields
            let text = eventNameField.text!
            let fromTime = fromTimePicker.date
            let toTime = toTimePicker.date
        
            //initialize object
            let currentEvent = EventModel(eventName: text, fromTime: fromTime, toTime: toTime, color: storedColor)
        
            //append to data model
            EventDataArray.append(currentEvent)
            
            //transition
            present(EventPage(), animated:true)
            
        }
        else {
            eventNameField.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have an EventPage class declared as type UIViewController, but upon pressing the save button with a populated text field a transition to a blank ViewController occurs. I've attached the class to the correct ViewController in main.storyboard.

Comment: You need to present an instance of your view controller, calling the initializer like `present(EventPage(), animated:true)`

Comment: this creates a new transparent pop-up viewcontroller instead of calling EventPage

Comment: add background color on EventPage to check if correct page is loaded.

Comment: Please check my answer, I think I understand what the issue in your code is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in here is that you are creating a new `EventPage` but it doesn't inherit from Storyboard.

#### 1

Go to the inspector in your storyboard, select your View Controller, and write an identifier for your View Controller (can be anything)

Write it in **Storyboard ID**:

[image]

#### 2

Replace

```
present(EventPage(), animated:true)
```

With
(don't forget to replace 'MYIDENTIFIER' with the id you entered earlier)

```swift
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MYIDENTIFIER") as! EventPage
// If you need to do any configurations to your view controller, do that in here.
// For example:
// viewController.label.text = "Hello, world!"
present(viewController, animated:true)
```

#### Note

If the name of your Storyboard file name is not called **Main**, replace "Main" in step 2 with the name of your storyboard file (excluding .storyboard)

Comment: No matter what identifier I use, it gives me the error that the identifier is out of scope

Comment: What do you mean out of scope? can you please give me the full error?

Comment: 'Cannot find 'eventpageidentifier' in scope' is the full error

Comment: try "eventpageidentifier"

Comment: with apostrophes

Comment: Hey it works, thank you! Do you know how to change the transition type? Right now its transitioning to a popover.

Comment: Happy to help! and about your other question maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/37723581/14016301