# Swift background color while pushing view controller

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, transition

I have two white view controllers. When i try to push a second view controller, i notice a grey background (basically it changes alpha value during transition). Is there any hack to disable this fade? I just want my background being white[image]

Comment: Have you checkt what the background color of the window is?

Comment: Both viewcontrollers have white color. window.backgroundColor is nil by default, i've tried to changed it but it's not work

Comment: You could set the other view controller to start with the color you like but when it starts to transition set that view to white

Comment: Have you tried my solution? I'm quite confident that this works.

Answer (score 6):

Using a `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` would definitely be the "correct" way, but it seems you really want to not use it.

If you want to "hack" it, then swizzling is the way to go.

Here is an extension on `UIView` that prevents the underlying class `_UIParallaxDimmingView` from being displayed.

```
extension UIView {
    static func preventDimmingView() {
        guard let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, #selector(addSubview(_:))), let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, #selector(swizzled_addSubview(_:))) else { return }
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }

    static func allowDimmingView() {
        guard let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, #selector(addSubview(_:))), let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, #selector(swizzled_addSubview(_:))) else { return }
        method_exchangeImplementations(swizzledMethod, originalMethod)
    }

    @objc func swizzled_addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        let className = "_UIParallaxDimmingView"
        guard let offendingClass = NSClassFromString(className) else { return swizzled_addSubview(view) }
        if (view.isMember(of: offendingClass)) {
            return
        }
        swizzled_addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

I would recommend using it along the lines of this:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    func transition(to viewController: UIViewController) {
        navigationController?.delegate = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}


extension SomeViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        UIView.preventDimmingView()
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        UIView.allowDimmingView()
    }
}
```

Of course if you want this to make it through App Store review, you will likely get flagged for the `"_UIParallaxDimmingView"` string. I would recommend initializing it from a byte array instead:

```
let className = String(bytes: [95, 85, 73, 80, 97, 114, 97, 108, 108, 97, 120, 68, 105, 109, 109, 105, 110, 103, 86, 105, 101, 119], encoding: .utf8)!
```

[image: gif]

Comment: This is great! Thank you, upvoted. Do you know of any examples with the custom transition?

Answer (score 3):

You can style the transition as you like if you implement the protocol `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. Here is an example how this can look like:

https://github.com/dasdom/DDHCustomTransition/blob/master/DDHCustomTransition/Transition/CustomTransition.swift

Comment: Seems like this thing is breaking swipe left gesture. Basically, i'm fine with standard transition, i just want to set background color to white

Comment: You can implement swipe left gesture with that. Just an idea because right now I don't have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do it using a custom `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` as dasdom said. You can just create a simple transition where you move the new view controller over the old one. This way the old view controller won't change color as it does with the normal transition. Adding a left swipe to go back shouldn't be too difficult as there isn't much going on animation wise.

Comment: Yeah not an acceptable to answer to re-implement back swipe gesture in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think there really is any other way. This is just the default transition animation. Don't think there is a way to change that.

Comment: Like explained here, on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app

Comment: Right, this bounty is for seeing if there is any other way rather than all that work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is [this pod](https://github.com/Enricoza/EZCustomNavigation) you could use.

Just install it and use EZNavigationController instead of UINavigationController and by default the behavior should just be the one you want.

You could also pass your own animator without overriding any sort of swipe gesture if you need to change it a little.

PS: this pod was not intended specifically for your request, but luckily should just work for you.

PpS: This pod will also add a pan-to-pop gesture from the middle of the screen (much like instagram). Actually this is the main purpose of the library, so that may be not what you want, but I hope it can help anyway.